# VSCode OpenOCD Debugging - inspecting a really large array?

Tags: embedded, stm32, vscode-debugger, openocd

I need to inspect the content of a large array I have in my program's RAM.

The array is 1536 elements long, and its contents are ever changing.

Every time I inspect the array in my debug window, I just get a "circle of death" / loading visual beside the variable, which never seems to complete. The debugger eventually cogs out / freezes causing me to exit the debugger and reset the whole process.

Is there a different way for inspecting large arrays such as this? I assume OpenODC needs to fetch all the data from the MCU and is breaking in the process ‍♂️.

Perhaps there are some OpenOCD settings I could adjust?

Comment: Have you tried running GDB from the command line and connecting to OpenOCD? It won’t be pretty but has chances of succeeding. Generally: are you sure it’s the debugger that fails, not VS?

Comment: I cannot be certain - I wouldn't even know where to begin figuring out if VSCode is the one failing

Comment: I"d start with running OpenOCD and GDB from the command line (to simply exclude VS from the equation). See [this](http://openocd.org/doc/html/GDB-and-OpenOCD.html) for details.

Comment: 1536 elements of what?  What is the data type?

Comment: openOCD  does not have problems with any size arrays. I would suggest switching to eclipse based IDEs as they work very well and you will never have this problem.

Comment: You need to ask VScode guys for support as openOCD and arm-none-eabi-gdb ( you must use this one, not generic nultiarch one) work without any problems